# postfix mails stuck in mailqueue

Tags: linux, centos, postfix, smtp, pop3

I ran into a problem, I'm trying to set up postfix mail server (I'm using webmin), everything seems to work fine, I successfully connected outlook to POP3/SMTP, but as soon as I send an email, it gets stuck in postfix mail queue, only errors I see are in messages log file:

```
Jun 26 22:53:55 cloudlix kernel: [2383358.247448] Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=201.254.34.86 DST=5.199.172.70 LEN=56 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x40 TTL=43 ID=26861 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35037 DPT=23 WINDOW=5760 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Jun 26 22:56:23 cloudlix saslauthd[23271]: do_auth         : auth failure: [user=shop] [service=smtp] [realm=] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
```

P.S If I try to flush mail queue - nothing happens.

Comment: you can check with command line ```testsaslauthd -u shop -p password -s smtp```

Comment: @ALex_hha Just tested it, result is - `0: OK "Success."`